# Scala updating/creating value in a hashmap

Tags: scala, hashmap

I don't understand this with Scala hasmaps:
How do I create a value or update one if it does not exist?

I am tryng to count the number of characters in a list of Strings.

I've tried this code but it doesn't work :

```
 def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
     val map = new HashMap[Char, Int]()
     chars.foreach(
        (c : Char) => {
           map.update(c, map.get(c) + 1)
        })
 }
```

I understand the returning type isn't correct.
But is my foreach loop wrong?
Is there a prettier way to write it?

Comment: I would suggest anonymizing code snippets so that they are not directly taken from the Coursera course assignments, especially in light of the recent "academic fraud" alerts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will answer your question:

```
scala> "abaccdba".groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(b -> 2, d -> 1, a -> 3, c -> 2)
```

Oh, and btw `HashMap` has a method `getOrElseUpdate` as to your original question

Comment: Thank you very much.
I think that updating or creating a map value using the previous value (if there is) can be interesting.
How Is it possible?

Comment: See the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html)

Comment: Well beleving the API GetOrElseUpdate update only if there is no value. Whereas I'd like to update always.

There is an update method but it doesn't use the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

If someone wonder how to use GetOrElseUpdate and find this post here is the exemple I found :

```
val map = Map('a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2)         //> map  :  
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)
val newval = map.getOrElse('b', 0) + 1      //> newval  : Int = 3
val updated = map + ('b' -> (newval))        //> updated  : 
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 3)
```

Comment: You can also say "Map(...) withDefaultValue 0" instead of using getOrElse.